# Office Developer Tools as 64-bit DLL needed for a 64-bit VSTO?

Tags: c#, dll, outlook, 64-bit, outlook-addin

I want to build a 64-bit .vsto Add-In for Outlook.

As the project template for this projects add the needed DLLs I checked them for being a 64-bit DLL with the tools *MiTeC EXE Explorer x64* and *DependencyWalker*. As those applications state, the DLLs **contained in the Office Developer Tools**, which are shipped with Visual Studio, are 32-bit DLLs.

So my question is, if I want to create a 64-bit Add-In, am I going to need the 64-bit version of those DLLs and where do I get them from, as Microsoft doesn't seem to provide a 64-bit version of those DLLs.

As far as I know each dependency in a 64-bit application needs to be in a 64-bit compiled architecture as well. Correct me if I'm wrong.

If you need further information just let me know - thanks in advance :)

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/building-mapi-applications-on-32-bit-and-64-bit-platforms

Comment: Aight, so that's what I meant with "each dependency in a 64-bit application needs to be in a 64-bit compiled architecture as well". But where do I get the 64-bit version of the Office Developer Tools from?

Comment: Did you search you machine for the files?  Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/migrating-office-solutions-to-the-dotnet-framework-4-or-later?view=vs-2019